# Wolfram Alpha and Logic - NOR transformation

Tags: logic, logical-operators, wolframalpha

i have some difficulties interpret some WolframAlpha logic.
I have this logical expression: !(a || b || c)
WA says, that it's minimal NOR-Form ist a NOR b NOR c.

But if you type it in, the truth tables are different.
However if you search for this (!a nor b) nor c
you'll get the correct answer.

Is this an WolframAlpha bug or do I just misinterpret the result?

Here are the links:

!(a || b || c) http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=!%28a+||+b+||+c%29

a NOR b NOR c http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a+nor+b+nor+c

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we consider NOR as a binary operator, then we need to treat an expression like `a NOR b NOR c` as either `(a NOR b) NOR c` or `a NOR (b NOR c)`.  Either way, it's **not** the same as `!(a || b || c)`.  This is in fact how WA treats the formula when you ask it about `a NOR b NOR c`.

However, suppose we consider NOR as a “variable” arity operator, that takes any number of arguments.  Thus we treat `a NOR b NOR c` as `NOR(a, b, c)`, where the NOR function returns true if and only if all of its arguments are false.  Then `a NOR b NOR c` is the same as `!(a || b || c)`.  This seems to be what WA thinks when you ask it about `!(a || b || c)`.

It does seem like a bug in Wolfram Alpha that it uses different definitions of `a NOR b NOR c` in these two cases.